# Git submodules, not sure if its the right thing to use

Tags: git, git-submodules

So I have a a repo with my nodejs server. We also have a webapp that runs as a stand alone webapp only as a single html file on enterprise servers. For our cloud version we need ot run this with a backend, hence I am using nodejs.

The thing that im no sure about is I want to keep the html app' repo form the node repo but ut needs to be inside the node repo. Node will look for the index.html that will come from the web app repos

so something like this:

```
nodeapp/ nodeapp.git
  /public/
    /webapp_repo/ webapp.git
      index.html etc etc..
```

The reason I want to do it like this is so we have one version of the web app, not a version for the cloud version and one for the enterprise version. so I can make changes to the web app repo and pull changes into the cloud version and the other enterprise versions.

Im not sure if submodules is the correct way to do this?

I dont want to commit the nodeapp changes with it doing anything to the webapp repo.
At the end of the day, I would probably make more changes to the webapp and pull that inside the nodeapp than the nodeapp it self.

***Or perhaps it makes more sense, that when I pull on the nodeapp it should also look for changes in the webapp ?***

Hope I am making sense..